# increase/decrease css width on click with jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I would need to gradually increase and decrease the width of a img element inside a fixed width and height div, let's say `+10%/-10%`, on click of a button. How can I do that? What I need to achieve is some sort of zooming of the img element contained inside the div (which has `overflow:auto`).

I'm using jquery and jquery ui because I would need it to be pannable. The result should be something like facebook covers, where you have an image which adapts to it's container (and that's already implemented) but where the user can zoom in/out the contained img element and pan it around to choose how it looks best.

I have no idea how to do it, please help!

Thank you so much

Comment: show us what you tried already. We already have the answer but it's better if we help you find out where you were wrong instead

Comment: This is a fairly straightforward issue to solve. Please edit your question to include the code you have so far.

Comment: actually i'm working on a very complex solution and i don't have any real code to submit, the code im working on is not mine and it contains LIFERAY variables and a ton of stuff i don't really know about.. i'm not skilled in javascript at all so a clean example would help me integrate it in what im (trying) to work on :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/7gVgX/**

### JQuery

```
$('div').click(function () {
    $(this).css({
        'width' : $(this).width()  * 1.1
      , 'height': $(this).height() * 1.1
    });
});
```

Comment: If you want to decrease by 10% then `/ 1.1`

Comment: nice! what i need would be something like a +/- button let's say outside of the div.. would this be possible?

Comment: @omegaiori http://jsfiddle.net/7gVgX/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can get an image's width by doing:

`var w = $("#image_id").css("width");`

to increase it by 10%, you can multiply it by 1.1:

`w = w * 1.1;`

and you can apply this change back to the image by doing:

`$("#image_id").css("width", w + "px");`

Answer (score 0):

simply get the current image width and increment or subtract it.

lets say css is:

```
img{
    width: 80%;
}
```

and some js:

```
width = $(theImg).css("width");
//remove the percent
width.substring(0, width.length - 1);
//now add value
width = width+10;
//set the new value to css
$(theImg).css("width", width+"%");
```

Answer (score 0):

or, with animation:

```
var el = $('#elementId'),
    w = el.width();
el.animate({ width: w * 1.1 }, 'fast');
```